# Find the largest and the smallest number in an array

Tags: code-golf, array

#### The Task

The task is very simple. Given an array containing **only integers** and **strings**, output the largest number and the smallest number.

#### Test Cases

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Output: 1, 8

Input: [5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 10, 5]
Output: 1, 10

Input: [7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5]
Output: 5, 10
```

Numbers in strings are not considered integers:

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, "5"]
Output: 1, 4
```

If there is only one integer, it is both the largest and smallest integer:

```
Input: [1]
Output: 1, 1

Input: ["1", "2", "3", "4", 5]
Output: 5, 5
```

#### Rules

- You can assume that an array will **always** contains at least one integer.
- All integers are positive (greater than 0)
- The order of the output doesn't matter.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!
- Strings can contain all printable ASCII characters (`32 - 126`) and are non-empty.

Comment: How are strings that contain quote marks represented in the input?

Comment: @feersum Wouldn't that depend on your language?

Comment: @feersum With escape characters probably, but if the language doesn't handle that, that's okay.

Comment: @MartinBüttner If input is taken from stdin, it should not depend on what language is used.

Comment: @feersum That's new to me. Even from STDIN `[1, 2, 3]` `1 2 3` and `{1; 2; 3}` are all valid input formats, so I don't see why it should be any different for string literals received from STDIN.

Comment: The rules of this challenge are not entirely clear to me. So strings are just ignored entirely? They're only there as padding/filler to make the challenge more difficult with respect to taking input?

Comment: @CodyGray Keep in mind this is an older challenge, and so what we currently consider to be “good” challenges may not apply. Ultimately, this is “filter out strings, then take the min and max”, but in 2016, such a challenge was considered good. Nowadays, we may not agree, but it’s problematic to apply the standards held in 2021 to challenges posted in 2016

Comment: @caird I'm not complaining about the nature of the challenge. I'm just trying to *understand* it. I thought perhaps that I was missing something about the rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Seriously, <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
,ì;M@m
```

[Try It Online](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LMOsO01AbQ&input=WzcsIDgsIDEwLCAiSGVsbG8iLCA1LCA1XQ)

#### How it works

```
,                              Read list input
 ì                             Remove everything but numbers from it
  ;                            Make a copy
   m                           Extract its min value
    @M                         Extract the other one's max value
                               Implicit output (max then min)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I was looking for such a command. But the docs are not easy to search.

Comment: I agree. The docs are my next big goal.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 <s>56</s>

**Edit** 2 bytes saved thx @Neil

Note: `x===+x` is true if and only if `x` is a number

```js
a=>[Math.max(...a=a.filter(x=>x===+x)),Math.min(...a)]
```

Comment: Why the outer `()`s?

Comment: @Neil what outer ()? Why on earth should I have outer ()s?

Comment: This returns a function, you still need to call it. (or just remove a=>)

Comment: Yes it's an anonymous function. It's quite a common way to post an answer in JavaScript @MichaelTheriot

Comment: @MichaelTheriot [By default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/20469), we allow submissions to be standalone functions rather than always requiring full programs.

Comment: Yeah, I've missed that case... :(

Comment: You can save 1 byte if will check `!x[0]` instead of `x===+x` https://tio.run/##fY7LDoIwEEX3fsXYFSRDeSvGlLUbv4CwKFgUU6kBYvh7bMEEg4mbSZp7Tu@98xfvyrZ@9k7BCyGdRl3EWLGRszQ78/5GH3VjUUo547SqZS9aa2Dpdsi83LZxJvgwEXY@lqrplBRUqqtVWZmPECCECBFCjLBD2CMkWjyC6@ow2ayEeEK1c0DQue9p74Ob1xo3v80UOQkpFZlq/hnfi0hMlinRD7lk/jojvm4igTmhORFZWs2A8Q0

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
hM_BS^I#1Q
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hM_BS%5EI%231Q&input=[7%2C+8%2C+10%2C+%22Hello%22%2C+5%2C+5]&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hM_BS%5EI%231Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8]%0A[5%2C+4%2C+2%2C+9%2C+1%2C+10%2C+5]%0A[7%2C+8%2C+10%2C+%22Hello%22%2C+5%2C+5]%0A[1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+%225%22]%0A[1]%0A[%221%22%2C+%222%22%2C+%223%22%2C+%224%22%2C+5]&debug=0)

#### Explanation

- `Q`: evaluated input
- `#`: filter that on:

  - `I`: the value being the same after:

    - `^…1` raising it to power 1
- `S`: sort that
- `_B`: create array `[previous, reversed(previous)]`
- `hM`: take first item of each item of that

The hardest part is to golf the removal of strings, which currently takes 4 bytes. The current approach works due to `^<str>1` taking the first Cartesian power of the sequence (basically, the list of the string's characters), but `^<int>1` is just the identity function.

Comment: Hrm, you could also use `*#_1Q` to remove the strings, which would be shorter if a variable was initialized to negative one...

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 42 bytes

In Python 2, integers are always less than strings during comparisons, so a simple `min(s)` will find the smallest integer. When finding the maximum though, we must filter out strings first. The anonymous function accepts a sequence and returns a tuple with the minimum and maximum.

```
lambda s:(min(s),max(x for x in s if''>x))
```

Example:

```
[1,'77', 6, '', 4] -> (1, 6)
```

Comment: You need a `lambda a:` stuck before that.

Comment: `if x>0` or `if''>x` save one byte.

Comment: @Doorknob, now lambda as suggested.

Comment: @grc, thanks for the tip. Saved a byte.

Comment: @Dennis, I did not know this.  I have edited the solution to make clear the comparison only works in Python 2.

Comment: Building up: `lambda s:(min(s),-min(-1*_ for _ in s))` (39 bytes)

Comment: Wow. That is some very nice work with the `-min()` trick. It took me a few minutes to figure out how it works. You should post that answer yourself. You will certainly have a +1 from me.

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, 8 bytes

```
|f¹Ṣ0,1ị
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=fGbCueG5ojAsMeG7iw&input=&args=WzcsIDgsIDEwLCAiSGVsbG8iLCA1LCA1XQ)

#### Background

In a perfect world, it would suffice to intersect the list with a flattened version of itself. Strings are simply lists of characters in Jelly, so while the original list would contain integers and strings, the flattened version would contain integers and characters, leaving only the integers in the intersection.

In the real world, both the parsers of both input and string literals yield *characters* instead of strings of length 1. The only way to pass a singleton string to a function would be to encode it "manually" as, e.g., `[”a]`, which is a character wrapped in an array.

This would save a byte, for a total of **7 bytes** ([Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZkbhuaIwLDHhu4sKWzEsW-KAnTJdLOKAnDM04oCdLOKAnC014oCdLFvigJ1hXSzigJxiY-KAnV3Dhw&input=)).

```
fFṢ0,1ị
```

Since that's probably not acceptable, we also need a way to differentiate characters from integers.

Jelly's bitwise atoms <s>desperately</s> try to convert their arguments to integers. They start by vectorizing until they encounter types of depth 0 (numbers or characters), then attempt to convert them to integers. For a character that represents an integer, this will be successful. For others, a dyadic, bitwise atom will simply give up and return **0**.

For example, bitwise ORing the list `[1, "2", "34", "-5", "a", "bc"]` with itself will yield

```
[1, 2, [3, 4], [0, 5], 0, [0, 0]]
```

By intersecting the result with the original list, we get rid of the arrays and the integers that weren't present in the original list.

#### How it works

```
|f¹Ṣ0,1ị  Main link. Input: A (list)

|         Bitwise OR the list A with itself.
 f¹       Filter the result by presence in A.
   Ṣ      Sort the resulting list of integers.
    0,1ị  Retrieve the elements at those indexes.
          Indices are 1-based and modular in Jelly, so 0 is the last (maximum),
          and 1 is the first (minimum).
```

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> <s>36</s> 29 bytes

Newbie here, so I don't know if there is any standard or universally accepted place/way to calculate bytes used, any help would be very appreciated!

*Edited as per manatwork & Doorknob's comment!*

```
->n{(n.map(&:to_i)&n).minmax}
```

**Test**

```
2.3.0 :076 > f=->n{[(n.map(&:to_i) & n).min, (n.map(&:to_i) & n).max]}
 => #<Proc:0x007ff7650ee868@(irb):76 (lambda)>
2.3.0 :077 > f[[7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5]]
 => [5, 10]
```

Comment: 36 characters: `->n{[(x=n.map(&:to_i)&n).min,x.max]}`

Comment: 29 bytes, using minmax: `->a{(a.map(&:to_i)&a).minmax}`

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
MinMax@*Select[#>0&]
```

---

**Test cases**

```
MinMax@*Select[#>0&]@{1,2,3,4,"5"}
(* {1,4} *)
```

Comment: Why is there the `*` there? It seems like you can get to 19 just by cutting it.

Comment: @ASimmons It is necessary. `MinMax@Select[#>0&]` is not a valid pure function.

Comment: @ASimmons `@*` is function composition, whereas `@` is function application.

Comment: `MinMax@Select[# > 0 &][{1, 2, 3, 4, "Hello", 5}]` yields a correct response

Comment: @ASimmons Try assign `MinMax@Select[# > 0 &]` to a symbol, or just evaluate it.

Comment: @njpipeorgan I appreciate that it isn't a valid pure function, but I don't see why it needs to be one in order to be a valid solution to the challenge?

Comment: @ASimmons That one works because precendence in your case is `MinMax@(Select[# > 0 &][{1, 2, 3, 4, "Hello", 5}])`

Comment: @ASimmons It needs to be a valid function expression [because that's our consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/8478). Otherwise, the submission would be classified as a "snippet" instead [which is not valid by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I see, I'll try to conform to that.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
{_:z&$2*_,(%}
```

An unnamed block (function) which expects the input array on the stack and leaves the output array in its place.

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B1%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%5D%0A%5B5%204%202%209%201%2010%205%5D%0A%5B7%208%2010%20%22Hello%22%205%205%5D%0A%5B1%202%203%204%20%225%22%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B%221%22%20%222%22%20%223%22%20%224%22%205%5D%5D%0A%0A%7B_%3Az%26%242*_%2C(%25%7D%25%0A%0A%3Ap&input=%5B7%208%2010%20%22Hello%22%205%205%5D)

#### Explanation

```
_     e# Duplicate.
:z    e# Map over list: a) take abs() of integer elements (a no-op) or b) wrap strings
      e# in an array.
&     e# Set intersection: only the integers will appear in both arrays.
$     e# Sort.
2*    e# Repeat array twice (to make the code work with single-integer input).
_,    e# Duplicate, get length N.
(%    e# Decrement, get every (N-1)th element, i.e. the first and the last.
```

Comment: I sugeested e) and e( to aditsu. He hasn't accepted that

Comment: @username.ak I don't think those are really useful. Adding a two-char operator that only saves a single byte over the current solution isn't something aditsu is likely to implement, and I also think there must be more useful features to use those for.

Comment: it will save 3 bytes: `q~_e(ae)a+`

Comment: @username.ak Well that's assuming that `e(` and `e)` would ignore strings or something, which seems inconsistent. And if it did involve comparison with strings it would probably fail the same way that `$` and `e>` can't compare integers with strings.

Answer (score 5):

## jq, 21 characters

```
[.[]|numbers]|min,max
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bin/jq '[.[]|numbers]|min,max' <<< '[7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5]'
5
10
```

On-line test:

- [[7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=[.[]|numbers]|min,max&j=[7,%208,%2010,%20%22Hello%22,%205,%205])
- [["1", "2", "3", "4", 5]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=[.[]|numbers]|min,max&j=[%221%22,%20%222%22,%20%223%22,%20%224%22,%205])

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
f x=[minimum,maximum]<*>[[i|Left i<-x]]
```

In Haskell all elements of a list have to be of the same type, so I cannot mix `Integer` and `String`. However, there's the `Either` type for combining two types into a single one. The input list is therefore of type `Either Integer String`<sup>1</sup>. `f` filters the Integers, removes the `Either` wrapper, puts the list as the single element in a new list (e.g. `[[1,2,3]]`), so that `<*>` can apply the functions given in the first argument to it.

Usage example: `f [Left 1, Left 3, Right "Hello", Left 2]` -> `[1,3]`.

Edit: @xnor brought `<*>` into play and saved 2 bytes. Thanks!

---

<sup>1</sup> actually it's fully polymorphic in the second type as the `String` property is never used.

Comment: Nice idea with the pattern match. You can save two chars with a reversed map: `f x=[minimum,maximum]<*>[[i|Left i<-x]]`

Comment: @xnor: very nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
MinMax[#/._String->Nothing]&
```

Comment: I still don't understand your obsession with `Nothing`... It doesn't mean anything special... Also, for 23 bytes: `MinMax@*Select[NumberQ]`

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Make use of "all integers are positive"! See my answer.

Comment: Nice solutions guys, I should have thought of doing it that way!

@LegionMammal978, `Nothing` does have a special meaning. Since Mathematica 10.2, it gets automatically removed from Lists.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) is a documented function in the latest versions.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
<?=min($a=array_filter($a,is_int)).', '.max($a);
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 minutes :).

Comment: It's [generally forbidden](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) to suppose that the input is already in a variable. By the way, you can save two bytes by removing the `'` around `is_int`.

Comment: @Blackhole Thanks. Didn't realise. I've utilised your quote removal :)

Answer (score 4):

### Perl <s>44</s> 39 + 3 = 41 bytes

```
@a=sort{$a-$b}grep!/"/,@F;$_="@a[0,-1]"
```

Requires `-pa` flags:

```
$ perl -pae'@a=sort{$a-$b}grep!/"/,@F;$_="@a[0,-1]"' <<< '1 2 3 5 4'
1 5
$ perl -pae'@a=sort{$a-$b}grep!/"/,@F;$_="@a[0,-1]"' <<< '1 2 3 4 "5"'
1 4
```

Thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for shaving off a few bytes

Comment: Which Perl version? For your second example I get different result: http://pastebin.com/judJys5g

Comment: @manatwork You are correct, Figure I cannot remove `sort{$a-$b}grep...`

Comment: The requirement doesn't state that the output has to be formatted exactly as in the examples and in this task clearly not the formatting is the point. So many of us just used what is handier in our language of choice. In Perl I would do it like this: `$_="@a[0,-1]"`.

Comment: One character shorter filtering: `grep!/"/`.

Comment: It says the array will be numbers and strings. All the examples in the question are with double-quoted strings, but I don't see anything saying they can't be single-quoted. I think `!/\D/` is necessary instead of `!/"/`, for one more byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 71

Thanks (as always) to @MartinBüttner for the golfing help.

Not competitive golf-wise, but its interesting to implement integer bubble sorting in Retina.

Assumes all strings in the input are `"` double-quoted and don't contain any escaped double quotes `\"`.

```
A`"
¶
 
\d+
$&$*a $&$*a
+`\b(a+) +\1(a+)\b
$1$2 $1
 +[a ]+ +
 
(a)+
$#1
```

Input is newline-separated.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=QWAiCsK2CiAKXGQrCiQmJCphICQmJCphCitgXGIoYSspICtcMShhKylcYgokMSQyICQxCiArW2EgXSsgKwogCihhKSsKJCMx&input=Nwo4CjEwCiJIZWxsbyIKIjIiCjUKNQ&debug=on)

Comment: I think you can use `<space>.*<space>` in the second to last stage because of greed.

Answer (score 4):

### *Mathematica*, 14

```
#&@@@MinMax@#&
```

Example:

```
tests = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 10, 5},
   {7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5},
   {1, 2, 3, 4, "5"},
   {1},
   {"1", "2", "3", "4", 5}
 };

# & @@@ MinMax@# & /@ tests
```

> ```
> {{1, 8}, {1, 10}, {5, 10}, {1, 4}, {1, 1}, {5, 5}}
> ```

Explanation:

When `MinMax` gets non-numeric input it reduces the problem as far as it can, then leaves terms wrapped in `Min` and `Max`:

```
MinMax @ {7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5}
```

> ```
> {Min[5, "Hello"], Max[10, "Hello"]}
> ```

Due to the automatic ordering that takes place strings follow integers.

`Apply` at *levelspec* {1}, shorthand `@@@`, is then used to pull the first argument of non-atomic elements.   Note that `5` is untouched here:

```
foo @@@ {5, Max[10, "Hello"]}
```

> ```
> {5, foo[10, "Hello"]}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 23 bytes

```
"@Y:tX%1)2\?x]N$htX<wX>
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBZOnRYJTEpMlw_eF1OJGh0WDx3WD4&input=ezcsIDgsIDEwLCAnSGVsbG8nLCA1LCA1fQ)

```
"       % implicitly input cell array. For loop that iterates on each cell
  @     %   push each cell
  Y:    %   cell's contents (either a number or a string)
  tX%   %   duplicate and push class. This will produce 'char'  or 'double'
  1)    %   get first letter: either 'c' or 'd'
  2\    %   is its ASCII code odd?
  ?     %   if so...
    x   %     delete (it's a string)
  ]     %   end if
  N$h   %   concatenate all stack into an array. This array will contain up to
        %   three numbers: minimum up to now, maximum up to now, new value (if any)
  tX<   %   duplicate. Push minimum
  wX>   %   swap. Push maximum.
        % implicitly end for
        % implicitly display stack contents
```

Comment: Oh, my bad :p. Nice answer though :)

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! A little too long :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 189 bytes

```
SELECT MIN(TO_NUMBER(i)),MAX(TO_NUMBER(i))FROM(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:1,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)i FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<REGEXP_COUNT(:1,',')+2)WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(i,' 0123456789',' '))IS NULL;
```

Un-golfed

```
SELECT MIN(TO_NUMBER(i)),MAX(TO_NUMBER(i)) 
FROM  (
        SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:1,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)i 
        FROM   DUAL 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL<REGEXP_COUNT(:1,',')+2
      )
WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(i,' 0123456789',' '))IS NULL;
```

The sub-query parse the array and split it to populate a view with one element per row.
Then the non numeric elements are filtered out.

I wish I could have found a way to do it with LEAST and GREATEST, but no luck with how to handle the array as a parameter.

Comment: You're leaving the `[]` in the array so you're not selecting the max or min if they're the first or last elements of the array. You also don't need your WHERE clause, you're already selecting aggregates so you don't need to filter. Search for numeric characters in your regexes and push the number conversion down to the sub-query (very little danger of pushed predicates) and it becomes 126 bytes: `select min(i),max(i)from(select to_number(regexp_substr(&1,'\d+',1,level))i from dual connect by level<=regexp_count(&1,'\d'))`

Comment: There's no need for a `+` in the second regex here as it doesn't matter if you generate a few extra rows (saves a byte). It's also worth noting though that if you have a string made up solely of numbers you won't ignore it here; that needs overloaded functions in the same package, so is not at all pretty.

Answer (score 3):

### vimscript, 25 bytes

```
g/"/d
sort n
t.
t.
2,$-1d
```

Yep, that's right, vimscript.

Expects input in the form

```
1
2
3
4
"5"
```

And outputs in the form

```
1
4
```

Explanation:

```
g/"/d    delete all lines that contain quotes
sort n   sort numerically
t.       duplicate the first line
t.       duplicate it again
2,$-1d   delete from line 2 to line (END-1)
```

The first line needs to be duplicated *twice* to handle the edge case of an input of a single number. This is because the last command will complain if there are only two lines when it is reached, since it ends up being `2,1d` which is a backwards range.

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, <s>40</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
sort -n|sed /\"/d|sed '1p;$p;d'
```

Requires a line separated list:

```
$ echo $'5\n4\n2\n9\n1\n"10"\n5' | sort -n|sed /\"/d|sed '1p;$p;d'
1
9
```

Thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) to shave off a few bytes

Comment: `sed '1p;$p;d'` saves a byte.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, <s>53</s> 36 bytes

```
@($args[0]|?{$_-is[int]}|sort)[0,-1]
```

<sub>Saved 17 bytes thanks to [@goric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10734/goric)</sub>

***OOOF*** ... PowerShell usually plays pretty fast and loose with casting, which is normally a good thing for golfing, but hurts it here.

Takes our input `$args[0]` and pipes it into a `Where-Object` statement (the `?`) that will only select integers and passes them along the pipeline, discarding anything else. Since dynamic re-casting happens on-the-fly in the background for you (e.g., `1+"5"` returning `6` is perfectly valid PowerShell), we need to use the [`-is` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847763(v=wps.620).aspx) in order to differentiate between the data types.

From there, we pipe that collection into `Sort-Object`, which will sort the integers from smallest to largest. The outer `()` is necessary so we can reference the first and last elements with `[0,-1]` (i.e., the smallest and the largest), but note we also need the outer `@` to force casting the output of `sort` as an array if there's only one object (as the result of the `?`, or only one object was input).

Comment: Take a look at the `-is` type operator [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847763.aspx). I think you could replace `.GetType().Name-eq"Int32"` with `-is[int]` to save 17 bytes

Comment: @goric Super awesome! Thanks for the massive golf!

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 35 bytes

```
x->extrema(filter(i->isa(i,Int),x))
```

This is a lambda function that accepts an array and returns a tuple of integers. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Julia has a built-in function `extrema` for getting the minimum and maximum elements of an array as a tuple. However, since the array can also have strings in it, we first have to filter those out. We can do that by testing whether each element is an integer using `isa`.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 23 bytes

```
[V=Uf_bZÃn@X-Y})g Vw g]
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=W1Y9VWZfYlrDbkBYLVl9KWcgVncgZ10=&input=WzUgMiAzIDkgIjEiXQ==)

#### How it works

```
[V=Uf_  bZÃ n@  X-Y})g Vw g]
[V=UfZ{ZbZ} nXY{X-Y})g Vw g]

UfZ{ZbZ}   // Filter out the items Z in U where Z.b(Z) is falsy.
           // For numbers, this the original number, which is always non-0 (non-falsy).
           // For strings, this returns Z.indexOf(Z), which is always 0 (falsy).
nXY{X-Y}   // Sort by subtraction. Small items move to the front, large to the back.
V=         // Set variable V to the resulting array.
)g Vw g    // Take the first item in V, and the first in V.reverse().
[       ]  // Wrap them in an array so both are sent to output.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

```
lambda x:[m(t for t in x if str(t)!=t)for m in(min,max)]
```

Try it online on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/iBnrXH).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES5), 105 bytes

```
function a(b){m=Math;b=b.filter(function(c){return c===+c});alert(m.min.apply(m,b)+','+m.max.apply(m,b))}
```

Usage: `a([1,2,3,'4'])`

Just trying :)

"Ungolfed":

```
function a(b){
  m=Math;
  b=b.filter(function(c){
    return c===+c
  });
  alert(m.min.apply(m,b) + ',' + m.max.apply(m,b))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
hJSf!>TkQeJ
```

Explanation:

```
   f    Q   - filter([V for T in >], Q)
    !>Tk    - not(T>"")
  S         - sorted(^)
hJ       eJ - print first and last element
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hJSf!%3ETkQeJ&input=%5B7%2C+8%2C+10%2C+%22Hello%22%2C+5%2C+5%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

The obvious answer would be this WhateverCode lambda

```perl6
*.grep(Int).minmax.bounds
```

---

If it has to be a full program

```perl6
put get.words».&val.grep(Int).minmax.bounds
```

The input to this full program is a space separated list of values

---

#### Usage

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &code = *.grep(Int).minmax.bounds;

say code [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];  # (1 8)
say code [5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 10, 5];    # (1 10)
say code [7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5]; # (5 10)
say code [1, 2, 3, 4, "5"];         # (1 4)
say code [1];                       # (1 1)
say code ["1", "2", "3", "4", 5];   # (5 5)

say code []; # (Inf -Inf)
```

Answer (score 2):

## , 16 chars / 20 bytes

```
[МƲ(ï⇔⒡≔=+$⸩,МƵï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B7%2C%208%2C%2010%2C%20%22Hello%22%2C%205%2C%205%5D&code=%5B%D0%9C%C6%B2%28%C3%AF%E2%87%94%E2%92%A1%E2%89%94%3D%2B%24%E2%B8%A9%2C%D0%9C%C6%B5%C3%AF)</kbd>

Not bad, not bad...

## Explanation

This outputs an array containing both the maximum and minimum. `(ï⇔⒡≔=+$⸩,` basically filters out all strings in the input, `МƲ` gets the maximum in the input, and `МƵ` gets the minimum.

Just a note: this is the first challenge where I get to use `⇔`, which basically turns `ï⇔` into `ï=ï`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 52 bytes

This is terrible -- there has to be a better way to check if something is a number than `type`. `polcoeff(eval(x),0)` is even worse, despite (ab)using the requirement that numbers are positive. `iferr(O(x);1,E,0)` is clever but a byte longer: `E` is required for some reason, and *p*-adic numbers like `O(3)` are falsy (i.e., `O(3)==0`) so the `;1` is needed.

```
v->v=[x|x<-v,type(x)=="t_INT"];[vecmin(v),vecmax(v)]
```

An alternate approach is just as long:

```
v->[f([x|x<-v,type(x)=="t_INT"])|f<-[vecmin,vecmax]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 124 bytes

```java
a->{int s[]={0,0},t;for(Object i:a)try{t=(int)i;s[0]=s[0]<1|t<s[0]?t:s[0];s[1]=s[1]<t?t:s[1];}catch(Exception e){}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVDLTsMwELz3K1Y5JZIbxX3waBoQByQulEOPVQ6u64JD6kT2plAFf3uw01biTi7j9T5mZ6dgRzauaqGK3WfHS2YMvDKp2hGAVCj0nnEBK//tE5scePi2LQT3IYtSV7AjBwYZSg4rUJBBx8YPresGs8mzNiGJJZjuK32ZBLlgEepTi1nouiKZmk2SZx6W9AeXPnjEhX9chfoKzZfYp2ieWs6Qf4TP31zUKCsFImqtFthoBSa1Xer11M22dHouso6V3MHB3RWuUUv13ms/H7U@GRSHuGowrl0JSxUWzpO4QVnGT1qzk4mxOo@FKuahEl9wdaClBCYEpgRmBOYEbgjcErizUdQ781/2ec/rFtwTcJto4pYMxe11nimDF1GWVdAfMBj9X2OCeTAUbUCdzmDiYephFgyp@UpkR7b7BQ)

Java 8 lambda function, takes array as input and gives out array `{min, max}`. Non competing, because the input has to be an integer array.

Fixed and -1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: You could make this competing by taking a list of Objects and checking if an item is an integer or String.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen done, thanks

Comment: `<i` now gives an error without integer-cast. Also, your initial code (and this one as well) doesn't work for `min`, since it will always output `0` for `min`. [Here is a possible fix.](https://tinyurl.com/ychck86o) EDIT: [Try-catch seems to be 1 byte shorter](https://tinyurl.com/ycecbwvj) than the `if(i instanceof Integer)`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh didn't notice that, thanks!

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZA9T8MwEIb3/oqTp0Ryo6YffDQNiAGJhTJ0RAyu64JDakfOpcQK/u3BSajETgafbN/d@z53GTuzqS6Eyg6fLc9ZWcIzk6qZAEiFwhwZF7Dtnv3H6xvw4GWfCd5dWZj4hJv4UCJDyWELClJo2fSu8dVQpzNq/cHkqM1vH8g1C9HYBtPA14QyqdN6E3/jpr7HdZ3Y1G7Q32ziOEP@ETzWXBQotQIRNs4IrIwCJb4Gnqam1iWuTTqKotrnnuIX5qzlAU5@mmCHRqr3nngYZWdLFKdIVxgVPoW5CjK/iahCmUcPxjBbRqiHtkBFPOj8LnM3MYU5hQWFJYUVhSsK1xRuXBj2@/iv@qrX9Qa3FLxTPPMmY2l3nIMkeRJ5rkk/wGjyfxdDVmQsWRJ7TjLvwqILSzIm80XITVz7Aw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
(⌊/,⌈/)⎕AV~⍨∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@5/2qG2CxqOeLn2dRz0d@pqP@qY6htU96l3xqKPrv1tRfq5XsL8fUIm5oanlo55t/9MUYIIK6tGGOgpGOgrGOgomOgqmOgpmOgrmOgoWsepcKKpMwfJAhZY6CkAdhgZAxehqQPogUkoeqTk5@UpgAzGUIVuoZKqEIY0uoGQINEjJCEQYgwgTJbChAA)

`∊` enlist (flatten – this makes all the strings into characters in the big list)

`⎕AV~⍨` remove all characters in the **A**tomic **V**ector (the character set – leaves numbers)

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`⌊/` the minimum across

`,` appended to

`⌈/` the maximus across

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 20 bytes

I can probably golf this... I need to implement type-checking shorter solutions.

```
γ fxd='nF~tH0ͺZkγZKγ
 _fx                 filter the input
    d='nF~tH0        checking for number type
γ                    call that "γ"
             ͺ       pair
              ZkγZKγ  the min and max of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 65 bytes

Here's the obligatory example of how Python 3 is worse (for golfing) than Python 2, because it *got rid of* weird behaviours, like "you can compare ints and strings, and all ints are less than all strings".

```py
def m(a):b=sorted(n for n in a if type(n)==int);return b[0],b[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 71 bytes

```
(object[]z)=>{var a=z.OfType<int>();return new int[]{a.Max(),a.Min()};};
```

Simple lambda which returns the min and max as an int array.

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), <s>90</s> 84 bytes

```
|*
*
=+
(sort (skip ((list @) +<) (curr test 0)) lte)
[(snag 0 -) (snag 0 (flop -))]
```

This uses a couple fun features of Hoon:

- I'm returning a wet gate instead of a dry one to prevent having to specify the type. This makes the caller typecheck the function instead of definition, which is perfectly fine.
- The function argument for `|=` is an unnamed arm, which is placed in the subject at `+<`. Specifying `a/*` and using `a` as the input is longer than just leaving it unnamed and using `+<` directly
- The same thing applies for `=+` - it places the variable at the top of the subject at `-`, so I save the sorted list as an intermediate and can reference it the three times needed cheaply
- The input specifies "All integers are positive (greater than 0)", which along with the fact the string will never be empty helps immensely. I can then slam the input through the type verifier gate `(list @)`, which converts all entries in the list that aren't a number into `0` and then get rid of all zeros.

Example of use:

```
> %.  (limo ~[1 2 "hello" 9 17])
      |*
      *
      =+
      (sort (skip ((list @) +<) (curr test 0)) lte)
      [(snag 0 -) (snag 0 (flop -))]
[1 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++20 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `std::variant` array, <s>139</s> <s>129</s> <s>127</s> <s>126</s> <s>125</s> 124 bytes

```cpp
#import<variant>
int f(auto a,int n,int&m,int&M){for(m=~0u/2,M=0;n--;)if(int*p=std::get_if<int>(a++))*p>m?:m=*p,*p<M?:M=*p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLbjpswEH33V4yotMLEURIS0jZc9rUvyQ9kI2QRk1riJjCrlSL66U3HBpTNBtUPYzw@Z47nDElVzS9Jcrt9k3lV1ip457XkhYqILBSkNm9VCZzpQ6HjS27inl7Tsrbz8M@yXbhsHy79Yj73qUxtvHaqsFHn3e4iVCzTADORzWczSp0qyl93eehUzKmC/etuj59@h@JFkrVnAXf5e0qWjaoFzyPSNrK4AEJiBSEYiQGvNRgkZdEoSH7zGpzIJ2SxgPdSnrGNnuPwumZgemnzWGQiF4Vq@oyT8484l0VctooiV4m8yrjS@nh7iEijuJJJX1CJRg017RcsSo@HEyVXArjMsxKsAkEA1hUs36TRLtDegMSnL33cAjjghrZAT9RLpj3IwRBXY5MPPtb1TNLPHHhSHdhan436enUgskb8l2q9WZbeR93gwVOtfpQnOiAfi5N71C2gnwzQ0KF923h/MCmmL6k/YVeHLaNl@htxYwfmyD/MEbr7@0RxznzSEdLrycIeh9DPRo8pXh1PpuiKgctgzWDDwGOwZfCdwQ/o/K8EdyB4Boqcn0yTV0vkTcDXA1xX61HWL5FlpWVkphibiRdZnjWB9EbkxN12uLNW2iJXh7UOG@uTqvlRexvo14z7lFk/ZTZPGe8ps6V6Bre/SZrxS3Ob42jCZDZz@T8)

### Explanation

This uses C++20's **abbreviated function templates** <sub>[(cppref)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template)</sub> which allow me to just put `auto` as a parameter instead of using the full name or a `template<class T>` declaration. It is wonderful.

The effective ungolfed signature is this if it wasn't a template:

```cpp
void f(std::variant<int, char *> *array, int n_elements, int &min, int &max);
```

Note that the second type can be literally anything. In the test, I did `const char *` because C++ string literals are `const char *`.

The input is an `array` of `std::variant<int, char *>` <sub>[(cppref)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)</sub> of `n_elements` elements, and the output is stored into `min` and `max` which are `int` references.

It then uses `std::get_if<int>` <sub>[(cppref)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if)</sub> to select only the `int`s in the array, and calculates the min and max as normal.

It also uses the [`x?:y` extension from GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html) which allows me to omit the middle of the ternary to calculate the min/max, as well as cheating a byte because GCC reluctantly allows `#import` in C++ as a deprecated extension from Objective-C, and trading a warning for a byte by using `int` as the return type without returning `int`

An equivalent C++17-compatible version would be this at <s>158</s> <s>153</s> <s>143</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>139</s> 138
bytes:

```cpp
#import<variant>
template<class T>int f(T a,int n,int&m,int&M){for(m=~0u/2,M=0;n--;)if(int*p=std::get_if<int>(a++))*p>m?:m=*p,*p<M?:M=*p;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```cpp
#include <variant>

void f(std::variant<int, const char *> *array, int n_elements, int &min, int &max)
{
    // Set min to INT_MAX and max to 0
    // C++20 guarantees 2's complement, so this is guaranteed to work
    min = ~0u/2;
    max = 0;
    // Loop through each element
    while (n_elements--) {
        // std::get_if returns a pointer to the element if it is an int, or nullptr.
        if (int *p = std::get_if<int>(array++)) {
             // if (*p > min) {} else { min = *p; }
             *p > min ?: min = *p;
             // if (*p < max) {} else { max = *p; }
             *p < max ?: max = *p;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 19 bytes

```
(&/;|/)@\:(`i=@:')#
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJwVy0EKwjAUBNB9TzF8QRMItD/JtzWDkKWHcOHGglDwAh7en83AvGH2Fs4zf3PszxZen3tvl3iaph2KjIIKwxUrNhfzlnHzRReYQ1i5URfK430cX6HR4mBlZmFlEhOHnnRoEhWnPKKMqP6If5rFGXY=)

- `` (`i=@:')# `` filter input to only integers
- `(&/;|/)@\:` apply min (`&/`) and max (`|/`), returning a list

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.grep(Integer).minmax}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlEvvSi1QMMzryQ1PbVIUy83My83saL2f4FCWnS0oY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CqY6CmY6CuY6CRWwsF1jWFCwOVGCpowBUaWgAVASTA6mDCCl5pObk5CuBDYBLIxusZKoEF4YxlAyBGpSMQIQxiDBRAmv@DwA)

*Slightly different from [the previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71178/83605) Ruby answer! The user seems to be inactive for a while, so I thought of posting it.*

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
0+∩₍gG  # main program
```

```
0+      # add 0 to each element of input if number, else append 0
  ∩     # take the set intersection
   ₍    # apply the following two operations on top of stack and wrap
    gG  # min and max
        # implicit output
```

It may be possible to take this down a byte if there is a command that only affects strings but not numbers. I couldn't find one after some basic searching, but its possible a single command exists that does that.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0%2B%E2%88%A9%E2%82%8DgG&inputs=%5B5%2C%204%2C%202%2C%20%22Hello%22%2C%201%2C%2010%2C%20%2222%22%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 27 bytes

```
[ [ real? ] filter minmax ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBa8MwDIXv@RUPQW5jLEmzrd1hx7WXXcZOaQ/GVRozx05tFwYlvz1TS0MneEL63pNapZMP0/fX5vNjhdaHXqVk3AGRjyd2miOEdNf2GJNKJiajI344OLZ4y7JzBqkzCpSosECNZ7zgFeON18JKLMUvnmSZ8SUigNZsrScx7tb8iWr6x@aJCgKVokq0oOvdODVoEFjZd@zQGps4oDeuV7/YiUf5/gH5fusIQzAutZLSvh98ZLDS3fQH)

Integers are `object`s, `real`s, and `integer`s in Factor, so we can save a few bytes by using the shortest class predicate word to filter out the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) (builtins only), 35 bytes

```sh
A=(${(n)@//[A-z]});<<<$A[1]\ $A[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn939FWQ6VaI0/TQV8/2lG3KrZW09rGxkbFMdowNkYBSOkaxv6v5UpTMFQwUjBWMFEwVTBTMFewAIqYAnlGCpZAGUMDBVOgAFAYxPRIzcnJB8qa/gcA)

Comment: NB, Zsh takes all inputs as strings and can't distinguish between `"1"` and `1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
'm¬iÔm!rUfâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=J22sadRtIXJVZuI&input=WzcsIDgsIDEwLCAiSGVsbG8iLCA1LCA1XQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D` `E`, \$3 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 2.47 bytes

```
zni
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdjVhlxGXMZcJlxKpkoQOQA) Output as `[max, min]`

Verify some more test cases: [1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdj1hlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWEHkA) [2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdh1plwmXEZcllyGXIYGXKYQaQA) [3](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdhN5lwWXIYGXEoeqTk5-UpcplymECUA) [4](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdiFhhARAA) [5](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLq_IyISyowMpoJRclHSVXpdiNSoZKXEpGQGwMxCZKXKYQFQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
     # Example input: 1, 2, 3, 4, "5"
     # The E flag tells the interpreter not to evaluate the input strings,
     # so they end up as "1", "2", "3", "4", '"5"'
     # The D flag duplicates the input. The zn command will automatically pop the top item.
     # We want to keep all the items on the stack, so we need the D flag
zn   # Push [max, min]. As the top item is not a list, it applies it to the stack,
     # converting each to a float. It can't convert '"5"', so it just ignores it.
  i  # Convert each to an integer (as the zn command converted to float)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
OƑƇṢ.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//2MRj7Q93LtJ7uLv7/@H2R01r/v@PNtRRMNJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMNNRMNdRsIjVUYg2BYsBJS11FICqDA2ACkDiIHkIV8kDaHC@ElgjWArZMCVTJbAQiFAyBCpSMgIRxiDCBKQnFgA)

Yields `[max, min]`

### How it works

```
OƑƇṢ.ị - Main link. Takes  a list L on the left
  Ƈ    - Filter keep:
 Ƒ     -   Invariant under:
O      -     Converting to ordinals
         This filters non-integers from the list, as O has no effect on integers
   Ṣ   - Sort
    .ị - First and last elements
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

Another Python solution: the mandatory solution using `lambda` was missing :)

```python
lambda y:[f(e for e in y if e*0==0)for f in (min,max)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYnBCoQgGAZf5bul8QdaBEvgk7QdjJSE1eKngz69a5cZmLnLc15pqtl868/G/bAoy@qFg78YDiGhIHi4Xhmj5Bv9G0UMiaLNcqs3h/SILFZNGAkTQc@Ejpm7Jq0ah7Y@m5T1Dw)

-10 bytes thanks to [aeh5040](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104303/aeh5040)

Comment: replace isinstance(e,int) with e*0==0 to save 11

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
function(l)range(unlist(Filter(is.double,l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jR7MoMS89VaM0LyezuETDLTOnJLVII7NYLyW/NCknVSdHU1Pzf5oGWNIQyAQA)

Takes input as a `list`, as R vectors (`c()`) will coerce everything to the same type, in this case, `character` if they are there.

`Filter`s out non-numeric values, then uses `range` to find the max and min values.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ℕˢ⟨⌋≡⌉⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9icmFjaHlsb2cy///ihJXLouKfqOKMi@KJoeKMieKfqf//WzUsMTIsMywiaGkiLCIxNiIsMV3/WA)

#### Explanation

```
 ˢ      Select the elements of the input list which...
ℕ       ...are integers >= 0
  ⟨   ⟩  Make a list containing...
   ⌋     ...the minimum element...
     ⌉   ...and the maximum element...
    ≡   ...and return it unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
kÈ¶sÃÍg[TJ]
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=a8i2c8PNZ1tUSl0&input=WyIxIiwgIjIiLCAiMyIsICI0IiwgNV0)

```
kÈ¶sÃÍg[TJ]     :Implicit input of array
k               :Remove elements that return true
 È              :When passed through the following function as X
  ¶             :  Is strictly equal to
   s            :  X converted to a string
    Ã           :End remove
     Í          :Sort
      g         :Get elements at 0-based indices
       [TJ]     :  0 and -1 (last)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```arturo
$[a][filter'a=>string?@[min a max a]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?P9NX2w)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 53 bytes

Based on [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65)'s [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71181/116593). We can save 1 byte if check `!x[0]` instead of `x===+x`

```
a=>[Math.max(...a=a.filter(x=>!x[0])),Math.min(...a)]
```

```js
f=a=>[Math.max(...a=a.filter(x=>!x[0])),Math.min(...a)]

;[
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],    // [8, 1]
    [5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 10, 5],      // [10, 1]
    [7, 8, 10, "Hello", 5, 5],   // [10, 5]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, "5"],           // [4, 1]
    [1],                         // [1, 1]
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", 5],     // [5, 5]
].map(a => console.log(JSON.stringify(f(a))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 17 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
∩⊔⊃/↥/↧▽¬∵'type⊔.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oip4oqU4oqDL-KGpS_ihqfilr3CrOKItSd0eXBl4oqULgoKZiB7MSAiYXBwbGUiIDMgImFiYyIgwq8xMH0KZiB7NX0KZiB7ImEiIDJ9)

```
∩⊔⊃/↥/↧▽¬∵'type⊔.
                .  # duplicate
         ∵'type⊔   # mask of types (0 for int, 1 for string)
        ¬          # not
       ▽           # keep
  ⊃/↥/↧            # min and max
∩⊔                 # unbox both (need this for one-int arrays)
```